# Mac mini (2018) Macmini8,1 Linux usb-c will not recognize certain usb device types

Tags: usb, mac-mini, t2

The Mac mini (2018) Macmini8,1 is running Linux with rEFInd. The mini has 2 usb-a 10 Gb/s ports, and 4 usb-c 10 Gb/s ports

**Problem:** On usb-c ports, "dangerous" devices are not recognized by the kernel, they are ignored on plugin like nothing happened

> "dangerous" devices include storage Samsung T5/T7 or networking
> Realtek 8153
>
> "safe" devices like mouse, keyboard and display works

Everything works on usb-a ports

```
uname --kernel-release 
5.8.0-36-generic
```

to run with T2:

- applesmc brcmfmac blacklisted
- tg3 so buggy it is not used
- csrutil disable
- Startup Security Utility: No Security, Allow booting from external or removable media

**How can any type USB device be made to work on usb-c ports?**

February 1, 2021: it is discovered that only devices that decide to use 480 Mb/s or slower work. No device selecting 5 or 10 Gb/s will appear in dmesg --human --follow

February 5, 2021:

The usb ports that are capped at 480 Mb/s are off the Thunderbolt controllers:

```
lspci -knns7e:0
7e:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ec] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
lspci -knns8:0
08:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ec] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci    ​
```

Comment: Apple's [Mac mini (2018) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP782?locale=en_US) state *"Two USB-A ports (up to 5Gb/s)"*.

Comment: Linux reports 10000 ie. 10 Gb/s on usb-a ports. Capable devices plugged in claims to operate at 10 Gb/s. The Intel hardware is capable of 10 Gb/s. Please comment if there is a solution to the problem, otherwise refrain

Comment: You already stated mice, keyboards and displays work. Therefore, you have answered your own question. Is this just about running Linux on your Mac? Can you be more specific about the version of Linux? What does `csrutil disable` have to do with Linux?

Comment: There are several devices that are recognized only on usb-a ports, not on usb-c ports. I am therefore losing 40 Gb/s of usb bandwidth and 45 W of usb power

Comment: Correction: lsusb --tree: the two usb-a devices available claiming 10 Gb/s only connects at 5 Gb/s on usb-a but 10 Gb/s on usb-c while the hub claims 10 Gb/s. So there is also a loss of 10 Gb/s peak speeds. Linux is Ubuntu linux-generic-hwe-20.04

Comment: Have a 2018 Mac mini. Unfortunately, all the USB drives I have are 5 Gb/s with USB-A plugs. One exception would be a Samsung X5 with a USB C plug, but this is Thunderbolt 3. So, I guess would not have an experience with your problem.

Comment: dmesg --follow --human outputs nothing when devices are plugged in so I suspect cause is T2 security filter

Comment: Since the USB type C jacks are for both USB 3.1 Gen 2 and Thunderbolt 3, I might guess Ubuntu can not yet handle such a arrangement. I would think the T2 chip is not the problem.

Comment: I have note enough reputation to comment yet, so here is an ‘answer’ instead. For me, devices are detected when attached on boot. I’m running Gentoo, though. Maybe check out the discussion on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Gentoo/comments/mlkc57/usb_drive_only_detected_when_attached_at_boot/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 1):

What is not working is hotplug of any device 5+ Gb/s on Apple computers with Intel cpu, 2016+

At boot time, devices are recognized by efi firmware. After that, any unplugged device is gone until again plugged in during boot

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211681

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1914845

[Mac mini (2018) Macmini8,1 Linux usb-c will not recognize certain usb device types](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411321/mac-mini-2018-macmini8-1-linux-usb-c-will-not-recognize-certain-usb-device-typ)

https://www.reddit.com/r/Gentoo/comments/mlkc57/usb_drive_only_detected_when_attached_at_boot/